# How a near jump computes an address in x86_64?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, ida

I try to understand assembly on Windows with the debugger IDA free.

For that, I compiled a C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    SIZE_T size = 0;
    unsigned char data[10] = {};
    ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), NULL, data, 10, &size);
}
```

By following the call of the function ReadProcessMemory, I reach the address 0x00007FFBD508AE80 :

```
KERNEL32.DLL:00007FFBD508AE80   jmp  cs:off_7FFBD50F1A08
```

This is a 7-bytes instruction encoded with FF25816B0600 (if I understand well, FF25 is the opcode for a near jump).

I noticed that :

```
0x00007FFBD508AE80 + 0x066B81 + 7 = 0x7FFBD50F1A08
```

which is the offset showed by IDA. So I expect that the next instruction to be executed after this jump is located at address 0x7FFBD50F1A08.

However, when I continue the execution (with F7 / Step into in IDA free), I reach the address `KernelBase.dll:00007FFBD29BAC90`

What I am missing?

Comment: FFh 25h is an indirect jump ([FF /4](https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/insref.htm#insJMP)) so you need to decode the ModR/M and indirect to a near address in memory.

Comment: I missed the "indirect" part. The content of the memory at 0x7FFBD50F1A08 is indeed 0x7FFBD29BAC90. Thank you